# first deleted repo from github profile , now Not able to Push

Tags: git, github

I deleted repo from github profile now I am sharing that project again to Github but not able to do so.

Comment: Try `git push -f`-ing your local history to the new remote, that'll overwrite everything on it which would be ideal if you just created a new repository where you want to import the contents of the old.

Comment: @SeinopSys 9.. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best site on StackExchange to ask this question, but here goes - the procedure is roughly as follows:

1. Create the repo in GitHub again
2. Set the URL of the new repo - in your local copy of the project: `git remote add origin https://github.com/your-repo` (or `set-url`, depending whether `origin` already exists)
3. Push your changes: `git push`

AFAIR they even offer more detailed instructions if you create an empty project.

Of course this assumes you have local backup, with `.git` directory and everything. If you don't, I don't think you can restore the repository - at this point I'd ask GitHub staff to undo repository removal, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: I created repository again with the same name. added as you said. pushed . got this message -
The current branch master has no upstream brnach
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
git push --set-upstream origin master. I ran this. then **repository https://github.com/my-repo not found**. I checked with **git remote -v**.  origin https://github.com/my-repo(fetch) origin https://github.com/my-repo(push) . any suggestion here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not use the *git remote add origin* to added new remote repository. Because the remote reference of origin was used by old github repository. Maybe some authentication information still resident in your local repository which prevent you from pushing to remote. Try *git remote add new_remote* to add new remote repository.

At the same time, you'd better create a new branch from old branch and use *git push -u new_remote new_branch* to push your code to github. Only one remote branch can be tracked by local branch.

Comment: ...thank you so much. but how to create new branch from old branch?

Comment: @JayPrakashThakur *git checkout old_branch* . *git checkout -b new_branch*, *git push -u new_remote new_branch*.